# How to Serialize C# Class with class name as root element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following C# class

```
[XmlRoot("Customer")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("CustId")]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("CustName")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I then use the following function serialise the class object to Xml

```
 public static XmlDocument SerializeObjectToXML(object obj, string sElementName)
 {
    XmlSerializer serializer = 
          new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), new XmlRootAttribute("Response"));

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
       serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
       ms.Position = 0;
       xmlDoc.Load(ms);
    }
}
```

My current output to XML is like;

```
<Response>
  <CustId></CustId>
  <CustName></CustName>
</Response>
```

But how can I get the response to look like;

```
<Response>
  <Customer>
     <CustId></CustId>
     <CustName></CustName>
  </Customer>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the `XmlElementAttribute` on `MyClass` (it's not actually valid there according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to an `XmlTypeAttribute`:

```
    [XmlType("Customer")]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [XmlElement("CustId")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("CustName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The serialization method can now be (identical to that in the question but without the second parameter in the constructor of `XmlSerializer`):

```
    public static XmlDocument SerializeObjectToXML(object obj, string sElementName)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            xmlDoc.Load(ms);
        }

        return xmlDoc;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a response object containing your customer, because that is what your desired xml shows as well.

```
[XmlRoot("Response")] 
public class ResponseClass
{
  [XmlElement("Customer")]
  public Myclass Customer {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: That should be [XmlRoot("Response")] if that was the case, but he's already handling that elsewhere. Though I do think this would give the proper output.

Comment: You can't use XmlElementAttribute with a class.

Answer (score 2):

You could define them like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("Customer")]
    public Customer cust { get; set; } 

}
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement("CustId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CustName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

By the way, the `[XmlElement("Customer")]` is not valid on your example...

Comment: And just noticed that there are 2 answers that were posted while I was writing this :) ...

Comment: I changed my question from [XmlElement("Customer")] to [XmlRoot("Customer")] which it should of been